# How can I learn to refutation methods in DoWhy Library?

Tags: causality, sensitivity-analysis

The refutation methods in the dowhy causal inference library are useful.
https://www.pywhy.org/dowhy/v0.8/dowhy.causal_refuters.html

I'd like to learn a theory that explains these methods well, but I'm not sure what to search for to find resources that explain them.
What materials should I look at for knowing them?
What can I search for to find the material?

It may be difficult to answer because I did not specify specific refutation methods to want knowing.
I didn't know which method among many methods was relatively useful, so I couldn't specifically select it.

If it is difficult to answer because there are too many methods, I would appreciate it if you could pick out a few methods that you think are most useful and let us know.

I'm not fluent in English, so it may be difficult to understand my question.
If so, please ask in the comments.

Comment: [Search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=causal+dowhy)

Comment: @whuber what should i do?

Comment: The links answer your question.

Comment: @whuber Which posts should I look at?

I looked through 12 posts, but couldn't find anything about the refutation method I wanted to know.

Comment: @whuber The reason I asked about 'refutation method' was because I didn't know what keywords to search for to know it.